# Solving integral of a function of derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm having problems in solving the following integral:

$$\int_0^z s(1-s)\left[\frac{A'(s)}{A(s)}\right]^2 ds - \int_0^z s(1-2s)\left[\frac{A'(s)}{A(s)}\right]ds$$

Where $A'(s)$ denote the first derivative of $A(s)$ with respect to s.Here $A(s)$ is an extreme value generator, for extreme value copulas, but that shouldn't be relevant for the purpose.

This integral should be simplified as follows:

$$\int_0^z \frac{s(1-s)}{A(s)}dA'(s) -z(1-z)\frac{A'(z)}{A(z)}$$

I actually tried several times, changing measure for logs and so on, but I don't see such solution!
Does anybody have any idea? Probably I'm forgetting some rule from calculus, but I did not find anything on integral of function of derivatives.
As always, any help would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: If these expressions are identical for all $z$, then their first derivatives should also be identical. But if I differentiate the second, then I seem to end up with a term $A''(z)/A(z)$. No such term shows up when differentiating the first expression. So that makes this equality seem dubious absent other assumptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "should be simplified" ? Somebody claimed it does? And why don't you just define $B(s) = \ln A(s)$, so you just have $(B')^2$ and $B'$ in your integrals?

Comment: Yes, it is proved in Caperaa, Fougeres, Genest (1998). I actually tried using logs as I said, but it doesn't seem to be helpful in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as simple as that:
Let's integrate by part the first component w.r.t. $g(s) = (s-s^2) A'(s) $ and $f'(s) = \frac{A'(s)}{A^2(s)}$, from which we get,
$$=-(s-s^2)\frac{A'(s)}{A(s)} |_0^z  + \int_0^z [(1-2s)\frac{A'(s)}{A(s)} + (s-s^2)\frac{A''(s)}{A(s)} ]ds - \int_0^z (1-2s)\frac{A'(s)}{A(s)}$$
From which, after simplification, letting $A''(s)ds = dA'(s) $, and considering that $A(0)=1$ (by the bundary condition in comment above) we get
$$\int_0^z \frac{s(1-s)}{A(s)}dA'(s) - z(1-z) \frac{A'(s)}{A(s)}$$

Which is the desired expression.
$\square$

Answer (score 1):

As a test, let $A(z)=e^z$. Then $A'(z)=e^z$ and $A'(z)/A(z)=1$, so the expressions in the OP would become

\begin{align}
\int_0^z s(1-s)\,ds-\int_0^z s(1-2s)\,ds
&=\int_0^z s\,ds\\&=\frac12 z^2,\\\\
\int_0^z \frac{s(1-s)}{e^s}d(e^s)-z(1-z)
&=\int_0^z s(1-s)\,ds-z(1-z)\\
&=\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{3}-(z-z^2)\\
&=-z+\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{1}{3}z^3.
\end{align}
Since these don't agree, the two expressions are not equal in general.

Comment: Okay I got it.. Do you think that would hold if A(s) is in [max(s,1-s), 1] ?

Comment: @AkaiM I'm dubious that would be enough, though cooking up an example where $A(z)\leq 1$, $A(z)\geq z,1-z$ would take more time.

Comment: Just tested the case $A(z):=1-z(1-z)$ using Mathematica, which one can check satisfies your suggestion. The integrals are too tedious for me to post them here, but they still don't match.